# Apache 2 reverse proxy to ssl local networked lamp app server - 95% working, except first page login redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

Dived into the joys of using apache as a proxy. Awesome. There is a learning curve to deal with but the payoff is well worth it!

I took the virtual host approach to benefit from having the same urls whether I access locally or externally. Everything is setup, apache mod_proxy is listening on port 443, redirecting all gitlab.mydomain traffic to lan based lamp stack and all is swell *except* when I hit the front page, after being redirected http://gitlab.mydomain/users/sign_in. I have to retype the https in the url manually and then all is well. Ditto when I post a comment on the projects page. For the login problem the application ([gitlab](http://gitlab.org/)) seems to redirect anonymous non-logged in users to http://gitlab.mydomain.com instead of the expected https://gitlab.mydomain.com.

I probably will have to dive into code tomorrow and see if it is at application level ie maybe a [$base_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/base_url/7) variable of some sort like in Drupal. Here is the vhost file, maybe I missed or broke something in there, any tips welcome.

```
############################################################
#
#  proxy related directives
#
###########################################################
#NameVirtualHost gitlab.mydomain.com:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
  ProxyRequests off
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
  CustomLog logs/gitlab_log combined
  LogLevel info

  SSLProxyEngine On
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

 # SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
 # SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

  ProxyPass / https://gitlab.mydomain.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://gitlab.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

- Just saw that NameVirtualHost is commented?!? is this not needed? Whatever, things are 95% working but the signup page is kind of annoying.
- Can someone with enough rep to edit tags please add gitlab tag to post?

Comment: Are you really proxying that virtual host to itself?!

Comment: @Michael - I have alcatraz.mydomain.com proxying to gitlab.mydomain.com.  Is something off in there? I truly could have misconfigured as I am simply a php developper and don't play so much with proxies all that much unless I really really have to! =)

Comment: `ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com` ... `ProxyPass / https://gitlab.mydomain.com/` ... I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't see any redirect happening there at all. If it's the gitlab application that issues the redirect, it'd probably be more useful to post that config.

Comment: @Michael - I guess it's a fluke this is even working? The way I was seeing it was I only want gitlab.mydomain requests to be forwarded.

If I have no servername, what will happen when I add jira.mydomain.com to the mix? How will apache differentiate the 2? Should I simply do away with using servername directive and have something like `^/gitlab` in proxypass directive? (Instead of /).

I was expecting that I had to do a vhost for each application but maybe it should all be done in the same vhost with specifically configured proxypass directives. Answer below for easy karma.

Thanks friend.

Comment: @Michael - Found a gitlab appache+proxy example config on github, servername is also defined in this example:  https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/apache/gitlab

Comment: Yes, but that example doesn't proxy to itself.

Comment: @Michael - AH! I get your point! The reason it works is because gitlab.mydomain.com resolves to a local internal dns server when called from the gateway. This local dns server specifies gitlab.mydomain.com as being 192.168.0.50, I guess I could just as well put the ip of the application server instead.

Comment: How do you keep all that straight in your head? :)

Comment: @Michael - It`s a 'feature' of [ClearOs](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/overview.html), comes packed with local dns server. I have that setup as main dns for whole network, and all local applications are accessed localy via this dns. Sounds complicated but this distro is just so awesome, anyone able to install linux from a dvd can have this up and running in minutes.

Comment: @Michael - Wouldn't having a hostname have a minor advantage if ip changes on gitlab? , or is this really a semantic error on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isssue turned out to be resolved application side. In gitlab configuration files one needs to indicate protocol is https.